# Vba paste range at the end of table in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote this macro in excel. But when i use end (xldown) commend it dosent work . Any suggestion?
I want ro filter a big table and copy it on sheet 2 . 
Each time i want paste table at the end of table(after last row of table)

This is my vba code:

```
Sub filter()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:J46371").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M9:W10"), CopyToRange:=Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:J1"), _
        Unique:=False
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:J46371").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M11:W12"), CopyToRange:=Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:J1", Range("A1:J1").End(xlDown)).Select, _
        Unique:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct but only slight change is required when you select cells to copy using xlDown

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Range("A1:J1"), Range("A1:J1").End(xlDown)).Select
```

Please replace the above line of code in CopyToRange and check.

Comment: I can not understand, what is the difference between your code and mine? i use it , it dosent work . it said that says refrence is not valid!!!!

Comment: sorry !  it dosent work . it said that "application defined or object defined error!

Comment: Use the below code and check:

Sub filter()
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:J46371").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M9:W10"), CopyToRange:=Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:J1"), _
        Unique:=False
Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:J46371").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M11:W12"), CopyToRange:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range(Range("A1:J1"), Range("A1:J1").End(xlDown)).Select, _
        Unique:=False
End Sub

Comment: @user3041372 : Please share your coed what have to done with the code i have post.

Comment: i use the same code as you write but it dosent work. I Find that i should write it :Sub filter()
With Worksheets("SHEET2")
    Set a = .Range(.Range("A1:J1"), .Range("A1:J1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0))
End With

 Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:J46371").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M9:W10"), CopyToRange:=Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:J1"), _
        Unique:=False

Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:J46371").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
        CriteriaRange:=Sheets("Sheet1").Range("M11:W12"), CopyToRange:=a, _
Unique:=False
End Sub

Comment: I want to do this code 90 times and the above code, that i found, don't work correctly for more than 2 times:((( any idea??any suggestion?

Comment: Check the below link and hope this will help : http://excelsemipro.com/2011/03/copy-data-to-another-worksheet-with-advanced-filter/